# Initializing parent scope variables in a closure

Tags: php

In order to initialize a variable in the parent scope from within a closure, I can do this:

```
$f = function () use (&$a) {
  $a = 1;
};
$f();
$a === 1; // true
```

My question is, is this a side-effect or is it intended behaviour I can rely on in the future?  I know I can simply add `$a = null` before defining the closure, but this can get ugly with a lot of variables.

Answer (score 5):

It is intended behavior due to the reference, from the manual [PHP : What References Do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php):

> **Note**:
>
> If you assign, pass, or return an *undefined* variable by reference, it
>   will get *created*.

Even before calling the function the variable is created and set to `NULL` since `use` imports the variable at the time of function creation.  Before the function definition you get a *Notice: Undefined variable: a*:

```
var_dump($a);

$f = function () use (&$a) {
  //$a = 1;
};

var_dump($a);

$f();

var_dump($a);
```

Yields:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: a
NULL
NULL
NULL
```